# JavaScript dynamically add method to Object

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, nashorn

From JavaScript I want to connect and execute commands to MongoDB.
This works fine: `db.collection.find( new BasicDBObject("{name:'Vlad'}"))`

How do I dynamically add methods to the collection, so I can call `collection.find(string)`?
My goal is to be able to do something like the following without recompiling the MongoDB Java driver: `db.collection.find( {name:'Vlad'} ))`

In Groovy there is a library which does something similar: 
[GMongo](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo); it has a nice tutorial on this page.
I would like to build the same for JavaScript Nashorn, and delegate all calls of `Cursor.find( Object )` to `Cursor.find( new BasicDbOBject( object ))`.
Is that possible in JavaScript?
I cannot extend the Cursor directly, this has to be done at run time, since the cursor is generated in the MongoDB Java driver.

Comment: Are you asking *"How to write a JavaScript driven shell"* in Java? If not then what exactly is the question?

Comment: My question is how to overload JavaScript objects with furhter methods at runtime.